# How to check if two actors/polyData intersect each other in VTK?

Tags: c++, 3d, collision-detection, computational-geometry, vtk

I am a beginner in VTK and want to check for collision/intersection between two `vtkActor`s. I have a list of actors to check intersection within them. I have tried many implementations from the internet but none of them worked.

I tried the following approaches after extracting `vtkPolyData` from the `vtkActor`s' mappers:

1. Converted the `vtkPolyData` into triangular meshes using `vtkTriangleFilter` and then checked for intersection using `vtkIntersectionPolyDataFilter`.
2. Did the same as above with vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter and set the operation to intersection.
3. Created a `vtkClipDataSet` clipper and gave it `polyData1`(say) as input data. Computed the signed distance from each point in `polydata1` to `polydata2` using a `vtkImplicitPolyDataDistance` filter. Then, `vtkClipDataSet` is used to perform the clipping operation using `vtkImplicitPolyDataDistance` filter as the clipping function. The resulting clipped output is obtained, and the number of points is checked to determine if an intersection exists.
4. I also used the voxelization approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023170).

All the above mentioned approaches didn't work. I could see that some actors were intersecting but no intersection was detected.

I have mainly two questions :

1. Why aren't these approaches work and is it even possible to detect intersection/collision between two `vtkActor`s/`vtkPolyData`s with tetrahedral as well as triangular cells in vtk ?
2. If it is possible then what should I do to solve my problem ?

Comment: Can we check if two 3D point clouds intersect ?

Comment: Is there any C++ library that can be used to check intersection ?